# How do I remove the first item from a list?

Tags: python, list

How do I remove the first item from a list?

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]   →   [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1649, accepted):

You can find a short collection of useful list functions [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

[`list.pop(index)`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/pop)

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> l.pop(0)
'a'
>>> l
['b', 'c', 'd']
>>>
```

[`del list[index]`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement)

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> del l[0]
>>> l
['b', 'c', 'd']
>>>
```

These both modify your original list.

Others have suggested using slicing:

- Copies the list
- Can return a subset

Also, if you are performing many `pop(0)`, you should look at [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque)

```
from collections import deque
>>> l = deque(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
>>> l.popleft()
'a'
>>> l
deque(['b', 'c', 'd'])
```

- Provides higher performance popping from left end of the list

Comment: You can also use negative indexes, which have the same meaning than with lists.

Comment: In my case, the time went down from 1:31 min. with `pop(0)` to 200 - 250 ms by using `deque`. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 264):

Slicing:

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4]
x = x[1:]
```

Which would actually return a subset of the original but not modify it.

Comment: if `x` is empty, `x=x[1:]` would leave it empty without complaining. `x.pop(0)` would throw for an empty list `x`. Sometimes throwing is what one wants: If the assumption that there is at least an element in the list is wrong, one might want to get notified.

Comment: I like this reply much more, as mutations is almost always evil.

Comment: If performance is a concern, pop seems to perform faster than slice:

["slicing the list carries a performance penalty of ~50% compared to just doing a pop of the first element. This penalty seems to plateau after a certain list size."](https://esaezgil.com/post/python_list_pop_slice/).

Answer (score 64):

```
>>> x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> x.pop(0)
0
```

More on this [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Answer (score 39):

With list slicing, see the Python tutorial about [lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) for more details:

```
>>> l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> l[1:]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 36):

you would just do this

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
l.pop(0)
```

or `l = l[1:]`

Pros and Cons

Using pop you can retrieve the value

say `x = l.pop(0)`
`x` would be `0`

Answer (score 21):

Then just delete it:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
del x[0]
print x
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: For me this is the best answer related to the question (if you want to keep the original list object). Slicing `x[1:]` does not keep the original object but might be quicker.  `pop(0)` is not required if the removed object should end up in the garbage collector.

Answer (score 11):

#### Unpacking assignment:

You could use unpacking assignment as mentioned in [PEP 3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/).

##### Solution:

You should try unpacking like the following:

```
>>> l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> _, *l = l
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

##### Explanation:

As mentioned in [PEP 3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

> This PEP proposes a change to iterable unpacking syntax, allowing to
> specify a "catch-all" name which will be assigned a list of all items
> not assigned to a "regular" name.
>
> An example says more than a thousand words:
>
> ```
> >>> a, *b, c = range(5)
> >>> a
> 0
> >>> c
> 4
> >>> b
> [1, 2, 3]
> ```

Comment: This solution (which has been around since Python 3.0) should definitively be preferred if you need both, head *and* tail. Do you perhaps have some additional information at hand about the performance compared to `pop(0)`? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

There is a data structure called `deque` or double ended queue which is faster and efficient than a list. You can use your list and convert it to deque and do the required transformations in it. You can also convert the deque back to list.

```
import collections
mylist = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

#make a deque from your list
de = collections.deque(mylist)

#you can remove from a deque from either left side or right side
de.popleft()
print(de)

#you can covert the deque back to list
mylist = list(de)
print(mylist)
```

Deque also provides very useful functions like inserting elements to either side of the list or to any specific index. You can also rotate or reverse a deque. Give it a try!

Comment: It is only more efficient in some cases, not across the board.  It has different tradeoffs than list, and why both exist.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use `list.remove(a[0])` to `pop` out the first element in the list.

```
>>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>>> a.remove(a[0])
>>>> print a
>>>> [2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: Why is this better than `a.pop(0)` or `del x[0]`?

Comment: OP is not asking about the best way to do it. This is just another approach to achieve the same!

Comment: Yes, another approach that has no advantage over the other answers.  There are any number of ways to do it.  Why not give an answer of `a.remove(a[1-1])`? That's another way.

Comment: You are free to add that another way! you have no objection over other answer that are suggesting exact same way to achieve the same!

Comment: My point is that your answer is worse that the other answers, and has nothing to recommend it.  There is no reason to use this answer over the others.  Just because it's "another way" isn't a reason to add it here.

Comment: @NedBatchelder Your point is moot. It's a extra method available to lists in Python, specific to this particular task, and for the sake of completeness it should be noted. The contrived BS a[1-1] example, on the other hand, it's not.

Not to mention that his answer is not "worse than the other answers" in any way.

Comment: I stand by my question: this seems weird and contrived, and has nothing to recommend it.  In fact, the first sentence is misleading, because you cannot remove the i'th element with `list.remove(a[i])`. With duplicate values, it may find an earlier element with the same value, and remove that one instead of the i'th.

Comment: Hey @NedBatchelder, the answer has been edited to reflect your suggestion, since it is the first element OP is asking about, it won't matter if there are duplicates or not as long as we are removing `a[0]`, Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You can use `list.reverse()` to reverse the list, then `list.pop()` to remove the last element, for example:

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
l.reverse()
print l
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]


l.pop()
0
l.pop()
1
l.pop()
2
l.pop()
3
l.pop()
4
```

Comment: Why do it so complicated when you can use `l.pop(0)`? You forgot to `l.reverse()` after using `l.pop()`. Your solution has bad performance

Answer (score 7):

If you are working with [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) you need to use the [delete](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) method:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

a = np.delete(a, 0)

print(a) # [2 3 4 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, instead of using `pop` like below, which of course will be 0, because the result/return value of `pop`

```
>>> x = [0, 1, 2, 3].pop(0)
>>> x
0
```

Using this below method will skip the first value:

```
>>> x = [0, 1, 2, 3][1:]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

One another way to remove the first element not mentioned here is to assign an empty list to a slice containing the first element:

```py
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3]

lst[:1] = []
print(lst)        # [1, 2, 3]
```

Unlike `list.pop()`, slicing doesn't throw an IndexError even if the list is empty, which is useful in some cases (and not useful in other cases).

```py
lst = []

lst.pop(0)         # <--- IndexError
del lst[:1]        # <--- no error
lst[:] = lst[1:]   # <--- no error
lst[:1] = []       # <--- no error
```