# Function which removes the first item in a list (Python)

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function which removes the first item in a Python list. This is what I've tried. Why doesn't remove_first_wrong change l when I call the function on it? And why does the list slicing approach work when I do it in the main function?

```
def remove_first_wrong(lst):
    lst = lst[1:]

def remove_first_right(lst):
    lst.pop(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    remove_first_wrong(l)
    print(l)

    l_2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    remove_first_right(l_2)
    print(l_2)

    # Why does this work and remove_first_wrong doesn't?
    l_3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    l_3 = l_3[1:]
    print(l_3)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426663/how-do-i-remove-the-first-item-from-a-python-list

Comment: @pigletfly: with some names-are-references confusion mixed in.

Comment: It's better to return values instead of in-place coding, it allows for more dynamically-typed, short code with less temporary variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Slicing a list returns a *new* list object, which is a copy of the original list indices you indicated in the slice. You then rebound `lst` (a local name in the function) to reference that new list instead. The old list is never altered in that process.

`list.pop()` on the other hand, operates on the list object itself. It doesn't matter what reference you used to reach the list.

You'd see the same thing without functions:

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> b = a[:]  # slice with all the elements, produces a *copy*
>>> b
[1, 2]
>>> a.pop()  # remove an element from a won't change b
2
>>> b
[1, 2]
>>> a
[1]
```

Using `[:]` is one of two ways of making a shallow copy of a list, see [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python)

You may want to read or watch [Ned Batchelder's *Names and Values* presestation](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html), to further help understand how Python names and objects work.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the function `remove_first_wrong` the `=` sign reassigns the name `lst` to the object on the right. Which is a brand new object, created by slicing operation `lst[1:]`. Thus, the object `lst` assigned to is local to that function (and it actually will disappear on return).

That is what Martijn means by "You then rebound `lst` (a local name in the function) to reference that new list instead."

On contrary, `lst.pop(0)` is a call to the given object -- it operates on the object.

For example, this will work right too:

```
def remove_first_right2(lst):
    x = lst  # x is assigned to the same object as lst
    x.pop(0) # pop the item from the object
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you can use  `del` keyword:

```
def remove_first_element(lst):
   del lst[0]
   return lst
```