# Send emails using python: how to form the message?

Tags: python, string, email, project, gspread

I'm making a program that will retrieve the data from google sheet which is a spending diary of how much I spend a week. After successfully retrieving the data, program will send an email to me that how much I spend day by day in a week.

Photo of my spending diary: [image]

I'm using **gspread** to retrieve the data, and I was able to retrive the data column by column using for loop

And it gives me data as a list.
For example, if I do

```
num_days = 7
goods = []

for day in range(2, num_days + 2):
    goods.append(worksheet.col_values(day))


OUTPUT: [['Mon 04/08/2019', 'Edeka 20.07'], ['Tue 04/09/2019', 'Edeka 9.77', 'Gym 60'], ['Wed 04/10/2019', 'Party 5', 'Jiujitsu System 30', 'Jiujitsu card 5', 'Jiujitsu Monthly fee 54'], ['Thu 04/11/2019', 'Laundry 3.5', 'Part 7.5 Euro'], ['Fri 04/12/2019', 'Edeka 5.95', 'Laundry 2'], ['Sat 04/13/2019', 'Food Festival 20 ', 'DM Hair Roller 3.25', 'Rewe 9.97'], ['Sun 04/14/2019', 'Monitor 224.99']]
```

So I am able to retrieve the column by column and put them in a list as a list.

That's all good. But I want to send email in this following format.

> EX)
>
> Mon:
>         Edeka 20.07
>
> Tue:
>        Edeka 9.77, 
>        Gym 60
>
> ...
>
> Sun: Monitor 224.99

And here is the photo of email that has arrived into my mailbox.
I want first elements to be gone to just show what goods I bought, excluding the date.
 [image]

**How can I form my message of email to be sent like the photo above?**

I'm currently using **smtplib** to send an email, but I don't know how to fit just goods that I bought into the message.

```
def send_email_for_spending(money_spent_week):
    with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as smtp:
        smtp.ehlo()
        smtp.starttls()
        smtp.ehlo()

        smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)

        # title for your email
        subject = "Here is how much you spent in this week."

        # Number of Days
        num_days = 7


        goods = []

        # it starts from 2 because column that has monday is 2nd  
        # column
        for day in range(2, num_days + 2):
            goods.append(worksheet.col_values(day))

        message = f"""
            MON:
                {goods[0]}
            TUE:
                {goods[1]}
            WED:
                {goods[2]}
            THU:
                {goods[3]}
            FRI:
                {goods[4]}
            SAT:
                {goods[5]}
            SUN:
                {goods[6]}
        """

        smtp.sendmail(EMAIL_ADDRESS, 'dudeindaegu@gmail.com', message)
```

Comment: You should keep using smptlib as it is the best email sending module in python (if there are any others). However, to fix your problem, you can add `day.pop(0)` after the `for day in range (2, num_days + 2): ` You can find more info about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426663/how-to-remove-the-first-item-from-a-list)

Comment: Oh that will work! However, is there any way that I can print it like normal sentence? for example, if I do **day.pop(0)**, it will print out **'[edeka 20.7, gym 60]'** like so, But I do want to print out **'edeka 20.7, gym 60'** like this without bracket. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Yes there is. After you pop, you can use the `join` method like so: `output="".join(goods)`

Comment: Put this after the place where you put the `.pop()` thing

Comment: @ArnavPoddar Yes, it worked perfectly fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a solution to your problem. You should keep using `smptlib` as it is the best email sending module in python (if there are any others). However, to fix your problem, you can add `day.pop(0)` after the `for day in range (2, num_days + 2):` You can find more info about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426663/how-to-remove-the-first-item-from-a-list). After you pop, you can use the `join` method like so: `output="".join(goods)`
Put this after the place where you put the `.pop()` thing

Comment: Worked like a charm :)