# TypeError: 'int' object does not support item deletion python3?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to delete first element from a list after i convert int to list but it always shows me this error :

> line 18, in                                                                                     del q[i]                                                                                                            TypeError: 'int' object does not support item deletion

```
my code:
fn = 10534
sn = 67
tn = 1120

fnn = [int(x) for x in str(fn)]
i=0
for q in fnn:
    del q[i]
    print(q)
```

how can i solve this error ?

Comment: What do you expect to get as print output and what do you expect to be left in the `fnn` list at the end?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the first Item from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426663/how-to-remove-the-first-item-from-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that [it is not recommended to delete from a list while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207461/5763413) your code could be refactored to follow best practices by creating a new list with the desired elements:

```py
>>> fn = 21345678
>>> oldList = [int(x) for x in str(fn)]
[2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> newList = oldList[1:]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

If you are constrained by memory, or are using a large list, use the following syntax instead:

```py
>>> fn = 21345678
>>> myList = [int(x) for x in str(fn)]
[2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> myList[:] = myList[1:]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

This will replace the contents of `myList` with the contents of the list slice.

A good item to review is [List slicing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-slicing/)